# URL with parameter containing a list of values in `toD` gets collapsed into a single value

Tags: apache-camel

I have a Camel route which calls a web service, and one of the parameters this service expects is a URL parameter containing a list of values, ie. `p1` in `myhost/myuri?p1=foo&p1=bar`.

I am putting that in a `toD` URI, as the parameter values need to be dynamic, ie. `<camel:toD uri="http4://myhost/myuri?p1=foo&amp;p1=bar" >` (omitted Camel parameters and variables for brevity's sake).

Camel is converting this to `p1=%5Bfoo%2C+bar%5D` (url-encoded `p1=[foo, bar]`), which is not accepted by the backend service. I have no control over this backend service and cannot expect its interface to change in the future.

Is there any way I can force Camel to call the backend service the way I want to, instead of it collecting the parameter with multiple values into an array-like format?

Comment: Can you post whole route? Or how you are setting parameter values

Comment: @uvytautas The route is a straightforward from `direct:start` toD this URL. Parameters are being set using `$simple{param}` in the actual code, but I've reproduced this issue with hardcoded parameters as well, so that's not the cause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another approach would be to use `CamelHttpQuery` header to along with `to`, not `toD` endpoint

```
<setHeader headerName="CamelHttpQuery"><simple>p1=foo&amp;p1=bar</simple></setHeader>
<to uri="http4://myhost/myuri">
```

Comment: This works, at least with `toD`. Also, if you need to use Camel-specific parameters, like `throwExceptionOnFailure`, you can add them to the `uri` and have the backend parameters in the `CamelHttpQuery` header.